# JavaFX tooltip causes MouseOut

Tags: javafx, tooltip

Simply put I only show buttons when I am hovered on the AnchorPane. I wanted a tooltip for a button, but when the mouse hovers on the tooltip this causes me to leave the anchorpane and everything disappears.

Any ideas? Using the stage for hovering to show or not doesn't seem to ever cause the buttons to hide.

```
//this is an AnchorPane
    this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        //Doesn't help: if(!micTooltip.isShowing() && !screenTooltip.isShowing())
                showButtons(false);

        }
    });
```

similarly the mouse entered shows the buttons. And a tooltip is bound to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ObservableBooleanValue hover = this.hoverProperty()
    .or(micTooltip.getScene().getRoot().hoverProperty())
    .or(screenTooltip.getScene().getRoot().hoverProperty());
hover.addListener((obs, wasHovering, isNowHovering) -> showButtons(isNowHovering));
```

Depending on the exact behavior you need, you might want

```
hover = this.hoverProperty().or(micTooltip.showingProperty()) ;
```

etc

You might also find it more convenient to use bindings instead of the listener:

```
this.getChildren().forEach(button -> button.visibleProperty().bind(hover));
```

(assuming you want all contents of the anchor pane to appear and disappear on mouseover/out; this line needs to be called after you add the content, obviously).